# Grep data from a file bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have file named shadow.lab4 which contain below characters and stored in desktop:

```
$6$bIhKGKp3$LSd47ADZexr.4rBm8y29DLPfd1kxwyuliCea8fExg0ohMT25OAEqUOxKm7t6dj/M50PjACjD.gn.VDD8f4MVy0
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the encrypted data by using grep command and store it inside variable encr. Then show retrieved data on the screen by using

```
echo $encr
```

My expected output should be

```
LSd47ADZexr.4rBm8y29DLPfd1kxwyuliCea8fExg0ohMT25OAEqUOxKm7t6dj/M50PjACjD.gn.VDD8f4MVy0
```

Do you know code that I have to use to get my expected output by using 'grep'?

Comment: The line does not contain `sekew`; there is no `:` for the first `cut`.  Your post is very inconsistent. Please update the input data to match the commands in the pipeline.

Comment: Also in the general case you should usually double-quote your variable interpolations; `echo "$encr"`

Comment: I have made changes to the question to make it more clear to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ENCR:**

If the encryption is always the 4th field in the string:

```
encr=$(awk -F "$" '{ print $4 }' shadow.lab4)
```

If the encryption is always the last field in the string:

```
encr=$(awk -F "$" '{ print $NF }' shadow.lab4)
```

Results:

```
echo "$encr"
LSd47ADZexr.4rBm8y29DLPfd1kxwyuliCea8fExg0ohMT25OAEqUOxKm7t6dj/M50PjACjD.gn.VDD8f4MVy0
```

**SALT:**

To access the salt, if it's always the third field:

```
salt=$(awk -F "$" '{ print $3 }' shadow.lab4)
```

To access the salt, if it's always the second last field:

```
salt=$(awk -F "$" '{ print $(NF-1) }' shadow.lab4)
```

Results:

```
echo "$salt"
bIhKGKp3
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. then how can I take $bIhKGKp3 (which is salt of the encryption) from that file?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you use `":"` as a separator for `cut`, but there's no colon at all in your input string. Change the cut part of the script to

```
cut -d '$' -f 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` way:

```
encr = `sed 's/.*\$//' file.txt
```